# Presentation of $SL_2(p^m)$, for $p$ odd prime

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

For $n \ge 2$, $p$ prime greater than 2, and $m \ge 1$, let $SL_n(p^m)$ be the [Special Linear group of degree $n$ over the finite field of order $p^m$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpecialLinearGroup.html) (that is, $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ and determinant equal to 1).

From [this Chiaselotti's paper](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/slnpresentations.pdf), I already know presentations for $n \ge 3$, but I am interested in the case $n = 2$.

So, is there any (hopefully simple) known presentation to $SL_2(p^m)$?

Comment: For those who (including me) want to know presentations in general, would you give a link or something for the case $n \ge 3$?

Comment: All groups of Lie type have a Steinberg presentation.

Comment: @Orat I've edited the question to include a reference to $n \ge 3$. It is worth noting that the presentation presented there is really ugly and I'm not aware of a simpler one. If anyone here knows it, please, tell me.

Comment: @DerekHolt I will search for it but do you have any useful link, please? I am new to group presentation theory and I don't know what a group of Lie type nor what a Steinberg presentation is. Thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305007295) is a useful link on why groups of Lie type each have a Steinberg presentation.